# Mono detect if running in interactive mode on OS X

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I'm developping a service on Mac OS X & Windows and depending if I run it from the command line or as a service it behaves differently.

This line of code on Windows works fine

```
Environment.UserInteractive
```

But it always return false based on mono source:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs#L358

Is there any workaround for Mac OS X?

Comment: UNIX and Lonux have their own ways to define interactive, so you might dig into Mono.Posix or other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source in mono and found what I was looking for!

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix.Native/Syscall.cs#L4838

```
[DllImport (LIBC, EntryPoint="isatty")] 
private static extern int sys_isatty (int fd); 


public static bool isatty (int fd) 
{ 
    return sys_isatty (fd) == 1; 
}
```